# Is there any difference between вероятно and наверняка in expressing assumptions?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, наречия

I believe that both of these adverbs are used to express "must" in assumptions. I wonder if they're completely synonymous, or if one carries a different set of semantic nuances from the other?

> **Наверняка/вероятно** вчера с Андреем что-то случилось.

*Something must've happened to Andrey yesterday.*

(... he never showed up, etc.)

Comment: certainly/probably

Comment: "Наверняка" is also more colloquial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact meaning of the words are as Vi said, one shows a high probability and the other a certainty. In usage, however, they are both used to express the same concept but, Наверняка is colloquial while Вероятно is more literary.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification - that's the pivotal point I was looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

- "Вероятно" is like "probably" or "likely";
- "Наверняка" is like "for sure".

If the statement about Andrew's calamities is expected to be overestimated (i.e. a mother which always worries about her son), "наверняка" may sound better.

Answer (score 0):

It might be added that until (I believe) around the early XXth century "наверное" meant "certainly" whereas today by some reason "наверно" seems to be more towards "вероятно" than "наверняка"